# ios - what is the right code signing configuration for an Ad-Hoc build meant to be transfered from itunes to device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, ad-hoc-distribution

I am learning how to create an ad-hoc version of the app so that I can put it on my local iTunes and from that, to transfer it to the device.

I created a distribution provisioning profile and named it Production Provisioning AdHoc. Then I added the device I am testing on to that profile.  Then in code signing, for the distribution setting, I set it to that provisioning profile, but what should be the develop setting? Does that matter?

The problem I am experiencing is that when I archive my project and distribute it as AdHoc, I am able to see the app in iTunes, but when I do the sync and apply to transfer it to the device, even though iTunes says the app is on the device, the app never gets installed on the device.

Please help me understand what I may be doing wrong and how to fix it.  I have been stuck on this since yesterday.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: why can't you use Xcode->organiser to install .ipa in to iPhone --

Comment: @Guru not sure that was possible. Could you please explain the steps in a bit more detail? I was following some documentation which may have been old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about iTunes allow .ipa transfer or not. But you can use Xcode to transfer .ipa to device.

Here is steps to install .ipa to your device.

```
« Open Xcode->Window->Organisor.
« Click on devices tab
« Drag your .ipa to your device listed in side bar.
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, how do I make sure that the production version gets put in the device and not the one for development?

Comment: check which code signing is used(production/development). Don't know how to check for .ipa.